# Understanding CanCan Ability and Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, rails-admin

I have Rails Admin with CanCan support in my rails app. I'm confused on one issue though. How does CanCan know what user is signed in? For example, my users can have different roles and through CanCan I assign roles for certain access into each table. When I go to `localhost:3000/admin`, I receive the error

```
 CanCan::AccessDenied in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
```

My `Ability.rb` file

```
  def initialize(user)
    if user and user.role.eql? :super_admin
      can :manage, :all                # allow superadmins to do anything
    elsif user and user.role.eql? :admin
      can :manage, [Location, School]  # allow admins to manage only Locations and Schools
    end
  end
```

So what do I do so that user's have the ability to sign in into Rails Admin? Do I have to manually create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `current_user` method available in your controller. Assuming you have that, if you aren't signed you won't have access to a current user, so you'll need to assign a user in your ability file if it doesn't exist. In your `initialize` method, add `user ||= User.new` to make the assignment if a user doesn't already exist.

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new

  if user and user.role.eql? :super_admin
    can :manage, :all                # allow superadmins to do anything
  elsif user and user.role.eql? :admin
    can :manage, [Location, School]  # allow admins to manage only Locations and Schools
  end
end
```

Comment: Ahh. I thought that might be it but couldn't verify in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default, CanCan will use whatever is returned by `current_user`. If you are using Devise within a namespace though (`admin` for example) then Devise actually will use `current_admin_user` instead. You can either create a `current_user` method in your ApplicationController (or some other base controller) that returns `current_admin_user` or overwrite the `current_ability` method to instantiate the Ability with `current_admin_user` instead.

(this is all assuming your Devise is using a namespace. By default Devise will use `current_user`)